# Sync users and groups from Google Identity to Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-workspace, google-analytics-firebase

At my company we have an organization setup in the Google admin console which syncs users and groups from or identity provider (Azure Entra).

These groups are successfully synced to our Cloud Platform Organization and also to our firebase projects. This means we can use SSO to login to Firebase.

However, the users and groups are not synced to our Analytics console which is linked to our Firebase projects

We have a SSO setup in the admin console (successfully), which is syncing our groups and users from Azure Entra and enabling login to our Firebase projects. We were also expecting this to apply to Google Analytics but we're having to manually add groups and users.

To work around the issue we've created an organization within Analytics Platform and applied a user policy to restrict users to our domain. We've then added groups and users explicitly.

How can we setup our Google Identity such that user access to our analytics platform is driven by our organizational groups and roles in the *Google admin console* rather than in the *Analytics admin console*?